# Any ride-sharing services for getting from Indiana to Texas?

Tags: transportation, texas, ride-sharing, indiana

I'm trying to get to Texas. I have family that I need to get to.

Is there any app or website where one can hitch a ride with people driving this route?

Comment: Craigslist has a ride-sharing section...

Comment: You can look at Greyhound. They may not have a direct route, but should be able to get you to Texas via some bus-changes.

Comment: Texas is a very large state. Where in Texas is your destination? And where in Indiana are you starting from? The route and availability may depend on your points of departure and arrival.

Comment: A bus is  your best option. Greyhound has direct routes one way from Indy to Dallas for around $150.

Answer (score 1):

There are many apps and most of them are a total wasteland, these days this is not popular in the USA. Examples: https://www.kangaride.com/rideshares/indianapolis-to-texas/in-territory does list two rides for you ... on October 30 and they are sold out and I strongly suspect they are actually the same ride just with an intermediary stop. https://www.shareyourride.net/carpool/USA/ lists 21 rides for California, 10 for Texas and no other state has more than four, many including Indiana features zero. If I put Indianapolis into https://www.rdvouz.com/find-a-ride I can see "8 people asking for and offering rides near you" of which five are offers, two in September, one in December, one in January, and one in April. That's the entirety of their offers for Indianapolis.

This is not Europe where blablacar (and to a smaller extent, motar) is a totally viable alternative to trains/buses especially in the ex-socialist countries with infrastructure deficiencies. There's less of a need in Western Europe with ubiquitous high speed rail.